# Sublime Text 2 - Focus a column (like in iTerm?)

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

I am using Sublime Text 2. I like to to use the 2 column layout so I can see 2 source files as once. However sometimes I want to expand one column to the full window (Similar to the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> command in iTerm).

I can use <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to toggle between a 2 and 1 column layout but the problem is, when going from 2 to 1 and back to 2 columns, all the files that were previously in the second column are all put into the first column and now the 2nd column is empty.

Is there a plugin (or command I am unaware of) that does this?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami

This one does it, but I am sure there was something in the default keymap

Comment: This is a cool plugin and a nice upgrade to the default panes. However it doesn't appear to have the specific feature I am looking for (which is temporarily make one pane fill the whole window - without destroying the other panes) Maybe I will just fork the project and see if that is something I can reasonably add myself.